# WCF Authenticate Client with database

Tags: wcf, authentication

I have a WCF service that supposed to provide service to several clients.

The WCF will have a Data-Access-Layer that will communicate with the database.

This is part of my design idea : [My Design](http://s15.postimage.org/apxri7mw9/Design_Idea.png)

[image: My Design]

As you can see - each client will connect to the 1st WCF service for pulling information (get product, update product), and also to the 2nd WCF service in a pub\sub manner, so it would be able to receive notifications about different things it wants.

I have a table in the database for 'Users' with all the users in the system.
(there is an administrator, a normal user and a technician).

My question is - how do I do the 'logging' in from the client to the database ?

My current idea - have a function in the services called **'Connect ( username, password )'** and when a client connects - it will pass the username and password to be authenticated in the database, and only if authenticated - the client will start sending commands.

Problem with this is - anyone can write his own client that connects to my service and runs other functions without authenticating. I can solve this by saving in the service whether or not the client has authenticated.

But is there a better solution that just having a 'Connect' function in the service ?

Hope there is something simple yet effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a custom user name and password validator that derives from the `UserNamePasswordValidator` abstract class and implements the `Validate()` method. Then you can validate the provided user name and password however you want. To learn more about setting this up, read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) article.

Comment: The requirement we have is that the client needs to input a username & password that the service will validate against the database. Is this method you have shown me good for that ? Where does the client 'take' the username & password it sends to the service from ?

Comment: This is a method for custom validation, so yes, it is good for using against credentials stored in a database. As for where the client "takes" the credentials from, that's up to your client design.

Comment: Thanks ! so you're saying it is possible to pop-up a window in the client requesting him to enter a username & password - and that will be sent to the service ?

Comment: Of course it is, but it's up to you to design it such that those credentials make their way through to the WCF services in an elegant manner. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx) sample application referenced in the article.